# Why doesn't the Gmail web interface support background-size specified in CSS?

Tags: html, css, gmail

I realize this is sort of an open-ended question, but as a front-end developer working on my own startup, email notifications was something I was really excited to style nicely, but when I pushed my templates I noticed that my nicely rounded avatars didn't render correctly because Gmail doesn't support the background-size property.

Why is this?

Comment: I would bookmark this link http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ which has an overview of CSS support for email clients. This will help to style mails within constraints of what is supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most mail clients will sanitize features of email content that may be able to break out of their container and affect the mail interface itself. This is one of the features Gmail has chosen to disable.

For a list of popular clients and feautres, see: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/